# Decomposing Fibonacci Numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers, lucas-numbers

This [link](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Fibonacci_Number_in_terms_of_Smaller_Fibonacci_Numbers) demonstrates certain decompositions of Fibonacci numbers into products and sums of smaller Fibonacci numbers, such as $F_{m+n} = F_{m-1}F_n+F_mF_{n+1}$.

I am wondering if anyone knows of more general decompositions of Fibonacci numbers with three indices such as $F_{n+m+k}$ or $F_{n-m+k+1}$ to name some examples.  How would you go about breaking down these Fibonacci numbers with three (or more) indices in a way similar to the given link/example?

Comment: Why not treat $n=n,m=m+k$ in the first formula, and then use the formula twice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method uses matrices. Let $\,A = (^{0\, 1}_{1\, 1}).\,$ A simple induction proof shows that
$$ A^n = \pmatrix{ F_{n-1} \  F_n \\ F_n \ F_{n+1} }. $$
The equation $\,A^{m+n} = A^m\ A^n\,$ implies your equation for
$\,F_{m+n}.\,$ Use the equation
$\,A^{m+n+k} = A^m\ A^n\ A^k\,$
for a similar Fibonacci equation and so on.